# How to format SQL DATETIME to comapre it to a given date and retrive one record?

Tags: java, sql, format

Hi have to retrieve one record of the db, this record should be the closest as possible to my paramter(date (YYYY-MM)), please bear in mind that the column in the db (sql server) is DATETIME, so I need to format it so I can compare it, here is what I have been doing:

```
public Document findByDate(String date) throws GeneralException{
    Document docs = new Document();
    String d1 = date;
    String delimiter = "-";
    String[]temp = d1.split(delimiter);     
    try{
        String sql = "SELECT TOP(1) *  FROM Document  WHERE issueDate >= '" +   temp[1]+ temp[0] +"'  AND issuedate < '"+ temp[1]+ temp[0] +"'  ORDER BY issueDate DESC ";
        ResultSet rs = this.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            docs = (Document) this.build(rs);
        }
        if(docs != null){
            return docs;
        } else {
            return docs = null;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex){
        throw new GeneralException(ex);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Date YYYY-MM? What do you mean by closest. Nearer to the start of the same month or the end? and does it have to be in th same month as in 2012-10-01 is closer to then end of 2010-09 than 2012-09-15

Comment: I will only have one record per month so if it is not the actual month it should be the previous one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want is th most recent record in the same or previous month, course we have to bear in mind that the month previous to December was last year...

You could mess about comparing month and year, but if instead of passing in YYYY-MM you pass in the end of that month, then it's just

```
Select Top(1) * from Documents Where IssueDate <= ? Order By IssueDate Desc
```

Where ? is the end of the month

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use String concatenation to pass arguments to a query. This is error-prone, database and locale-dependant, and makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Instead, use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), and pass your date argument as a java.sql.Date, instead of passing it as a String:

```
String sql = 
    "SELECT TOP(1) * FROM Document WHERE issueDate >= ? AND issuedate < ? ORDER BY issueDate DESC";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setDate(1, date);
stmt.setDate(2, date);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

That said, I don't see how your query could possibly work. How can a date in database be both less or equal to a given date, and greater than the same date? Maybe you should use your date as lowest bound, and your date + 1 month as upper bound?

Comment: I will only have one record per month so if it is not the actual month it should be the previous one

Comment: That doesn't explain how `a >= b and a < b` can ever be true.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT TOP(1) *  FROM Document  WHERE convert(date,issueDate) >= ' datevalue ' AND convert(date,issuedate) < ' datevalue '  ORDER BY issueDate DESC
```